# Easier way to prevent IAP cross-store installation issues

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, google-play, galaxy

We have an app / game in the Google Play Store. We plan to eventually release the game in the Samsung Galaxy Store.

One of the issues we have is how to prevent [IAP cross-store installation issues](https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.3/Documentation/Manual/UnityIAPCrossStoreInstallationIssues.html) in an easy and more manageable way.

Currently, the [recommended way](https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy-games/recommendations-to-bring-your-game.html) is to use a different package name for different stores. The problem with this is our app uses Firebase, Facebook and other integrations that rely on the package name. Changing the package name would mean those integrations will be affected and stop working, and we would have to do all kinds of extra work and configurations just to get the Galaxy Store version working. It would also mean that we might have to maintain two codebases as the integrations for the Play Store and Galaxy Store may not be able to co-exist in the same codebase.

Is there an easier way around this?